# Reading multidimensional vectors from a file

Tags: c++, file, vector, dimensions

I need to read values from a txt file into a n x 20 vector. The file is like that

```
pipe 1 2 0 1 1 50 120 5 5 6 0 0
pipe 2 3 0 1 1 50 120 4 5 2 0 0
pipe 3 4 0 1 1 25 120 1 5 4 80 90
```

The code I came up with is as follows

```
vector<double> aRow;
vector< vector < double >> aPipes;

ifstream inf("F:\\text.txt");
while (inf >> c0 >> c1 >> c2 >> c3 >> c4 >> c5 >> c6 >> c7 >> c8 >> c9 >> c10 >> c11 >> c12)
    {
        if (c0 == "pipe")
        {
                aRow.push_back(c1);          
                aRow.push_back(c2);         
                aRow.push_back(0);           
                aRow.push_back(c4);          
                aRow.push_back(c5);          
                aRow.push_back(c6);          
                aRow.push_back(c7);         
                aRow.push_back(c8);          
                aRow.push_back(c9);          
                aRow.push_back(c10);         
                aRow.push_back(c11);         
                aRow.push_back(c12);         
                aRow.push_back(0);          
                aRow.push_back(0);           
                aRow.push_back(0);           
                aRow.push_back(0);           
                aRow.push_back(0);           
                aRow.push_back(0);           
                aRow.push_back(0);           
                aRow.push_back(0);           
                aPipes.push_back(aRow);
            i++;
        }
    }

nNumPipes = i;
cout << "Num of pipes: " << nNumPipes << endl;
```

However when I print the entire vector such as this,

```
for (int i = 0; i < nNumPipes; i++)
{
      {for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
            cout << setprecision(3) << aPipes.at(i).at(j) << "\t";
            cout << endl;
      }
}
```

the matrix shows all lines but they are all duplicate of the first. For some reason only the first line is read.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Because you need to a loop which read all the lines of your files. The way that you solve your problem is not good. You should write a function which transform a line into a vector and call this function of every line of your file.

Comment: After `aPipes.push_back(aRow);` add `aRow.clear();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to clear `aRow` before reusing it. Otherwise you keep pushing the same values into your matrix.

After `aPipes.push_back(aRow);` add `aRow.clear();`